# Merging Several Data Sets in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database in mysql with several different tables I would like to create one table.

Three of the the tables (A,B,C) have the same primary key and the last has a different primary key. So it might look like

### Table A

### ID | Phone| Address

---

### Table B

### ID| WorkPhone | Phone | Address

---

### Table C

### ID| Phone| Work_Address| WorkPhone

The biggest problem is that some of the information might be different despite the same ID. (So ID "Person1" might have two different phone numbers in the column "Phone" in the three tables.

For the first three tables, I'm trying to map them together but having problem with my syntax in MYSQL.

Here is what I have so far.

```
create table Total_Finance(

select combined_csv.*, finance.*, total_contribution.*

join

where combined_csv.id == finance.id

inner join 
where total_contribution.nationbuilder_id == combined_csv.nationbuilder_id

inner join 
where total_contribution.nationbuilder_id == finance.nationbuilder_id


);
```

Comment: JOIN sintax SELECT something FROM table name JOIN table name ON condition... something like SELECT combined_csv.*, finance.* FROM combined_csv JOIN finance ON combined_csv.id = finance.id... and you don't need this create table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is how you should do JOIN sintax

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*, tableC.*
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
INNER JOIN tableC
ON tableA.ID = tableC.ID
```

and here is SQL Fiddle for that to see how it's work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d36f8/1

of course you can choose which column you want to select to do that instead of

```
 SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*, tableC.*
```

write

```
SELECT tableA.ID, tableA.Phone, ... tableB.Address... tableC.WorkPhone etc
```

Also about JOIN sintax you should know that there is a LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN etc... you can see basics of that here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Hope this help a little... if you have any question fill free to ask

GL!